# How to add namespace to xml intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xsd, xsd-validation

I have below schema:
Main XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:firstNamespace="firstNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="mainNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation=".\firstChild.xsd" namespace="firstNamespace" />
    <xs:element name="firstElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:group ref="firstNamespace:group" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="secondElement" type="xs:date" />
</xs:schema>
```

Child xsd (with different namespace):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns0="firstNamespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="firstNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="firstElement" type="xs:date" />
    <xs:element name="secondElement" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:group name="group">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="tns0:firstElement" />
            <xs:element ref="tns0:secondElement" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

When i add this schema to Visual Studio, i've got next thing:
[Screenshot from MS Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KV5b.png)
Elements namespaces doesn't appear before elements name. For example:

```
<firstElement xmlns="mainNamespace">
  <firstElement xmlns="firstNamespace"/>  
</firstElement>
```

But i need to see namespaces and be able to select elements by namespaces. Example:

```
<mainNamespace:firstElement>
  <firstNamespace:firstElement/>  
</mainNamespace:firstElement>
```

Can someone explain me why namespaces doesn't appear in Visual Studio or give example with right realization.

Many thanks.